# geom_point and geom_col fill color change and legend label change

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
df = data.frame(
  measure = c("Measure A","Measure B","Measure C"),
  overall = c(9, 5, 11),
  company = c(4,6,3)
)
```

I am trying to plot bars for the company, and using geom_point, "lines" for the overall.  For some reason, the company color fill and label for the legend doesn't change even though my code specifies it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(measure)) + geom_col(aes(y=company, fill="company")) + geom_point(aes(y=overall, color="overall"), size=8, shape=124) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("company" = "yellow", "overall"="blue"),labels=c("company" = "Your Company", "overall"= "Overall Benchmark")) +
  coord_flip()+ guides(size=FALSE) + theme(legend.box="horizontal",legend.key=element_blank(), legend.title=element_blank(),legend.position="top")
```

The bars stay red and the legend reads company regardless.  Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You used `fill` for the bars.  `scale_color_manual` is for `color`, not `fill`.  Use `scale_fill_manual` to change the `fill` color and labels.

Comment: That makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the quotes from `fill = "company"`. It should work as you expect.

Here's the full source code again, but with the mentioned fix and also respecting [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#assignment) for indentation, it does help on readability and finding missed pieces like that :).

```
df = data.frame(
measure = c("Measure A", "Measure B", "Measure C"),
overall = c(9, 5, 11),
company = c(4, 6, 3)
)

ggplot(df, aes(measure)) +
geom_col(aes(y    = company,
            fill  = company)) +
geom_point(aes(y      = overall,
                color = "overall"),
            size = 8,
            shape = 124) +
scale_color_manual(
    values = c("company" = "yellow",
            "overall"    = "blue"),
    labels = c("company" = "Your Company",
            "overall"    = "Overall Benchmark")
) +
coord_flip() +
guides(size = FALSE) +
theme(
    legend.box      = "horizontal",
    legend.key      = element_blank(),
    legend.title    = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top"
)
```

[image]